# Override NotificationStore from AbpZeroModule

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I need to override some methods of NotificationStore, so I created my own class extending Abp.Notifications.NotificationStore

Where should I tell to the framework to use my implementation instead of the Abp Module Zero NotificationStore.

I've tried to call the iocManager.register in the Core Module, but the NotificationStore are still being calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation on [Replacing Built-In Services](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Startup-Configuration#replacing-built-in-services).

```
// using Abp.Configuration.Startup;

Configuration.ReplaceService<INotificationStore, MyNotificationStore>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```